# The gap of cards in Materialize.css

Tags: css, materialize

```css
 .card .card-image {
  padding-top: 10px;
 }

 .card {
  width:100%;
  /*min-height:250px;*/
  background:rgba(255,255,255,1);
  border-radius:8px;
  text-align: center;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  /*margin: 10px 0px;*/
  padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  /*position: relative;*/
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  display: inline-block;
     overflow: visible;
 }

.row .col.s6 {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
}

.row .col {
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 .75rem;
    min-height: 1px;
}

.row .col.s12 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
}
```

```html
 <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="col s12 active">            
<div class="contents-tabs">
 <div class="col s6 cards-container" style="padding: 0 5px !important;">
       <div class="card">
         <div class="card-image">
            <img src="http://localhost/storage/uploads/1/Razer40996862167@3x_c.png">
         </div>
         <div class="card-content">
            <div class="row">
             <div class="progress">
      <div class="determinate" id="par1" style="width: 0.016722408026756%"></div>
     </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
     <div class="col s8">
      <div class="contents event-status event-status-left">
       <p>目前人数 <b><span id="left1">1</span></b></p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col s4">
      <div class="contents event-status event-status-req">
       <p><b>5980</b></p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <sup>第1期</sup> 雷蛇 蝰蛇2000穿越火线+萨诺狼蛛专业键盘 套装
    </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
           <div class="col s6 cards-container" style="padding: 0 5px !important;">
       <div class="card">
         <div class="card-image">
            <img src="http://localhost/storage/uploads/2/Razer26838583992@3x_c.png">
         </div>
         <div class="card-content">
            <div class="row">
             <div class="progress">
      <div class="determinate" id="par2" style="width: 0.033557046979866%"></div>
     </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
     <div class="col s8">
      <div class="contents event-status event-status-left">
       <p>目前人数 <b><span id="left2">1</span></b></p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col s4">
      <div class="contents event-status event-status-req">
       <p><b>2980</b></p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <sup>第1期</sup> 雷蛇 炼狱蝰蛇游戏鼠标 6400dpi 标准版黑色（旗舰）
    </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
           <div class="col s6 cards-container" style="padding: 0 5px !important;">
       <div class="card">
         <div class="card-image">
            <img src="http://localhost/storage/uploads/3/Razer6095225@3x_c.png">
         </div>
         <div class="card-content">
            <div class="row">
             <div class="progress">
      <div class="determinate" id="par3" style="width: 0%"></div>
     </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
     <div class="col s8">
      <div class="contents event-status event-status-left">
       <p>目前人数 <b><span id="left3">0</span></b></p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col s4">
      <div class="contents event-status event-status-req">
       <p><b>8580</b></p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <sup>第1期</sup> 雷蛇 锐蝮蛇Lancehead TE竞技版-粉晶鼠标 韦神同款
    </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
           <div class="col s6 cards-container" style="padding: 0 5px !important;">
       <div class="card">
         <div class="card-image">
            <img src="http://localhost/storage/uploads/4/Razer1772859@3x_c.png">
         </div>
         <div class="card-content">
            <div class="row">
             <div class="progress">
      <div class="determinate" id="par4" style="width: 0.02092050209205%"></div>
     </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
     <div class="col s8">
      <div class="contents event-status event-status-left">
       <p>目前人数 <b><span id="left4">1</span></b></p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col s4">
      <div class="contents event-status event-status-req">
       <p><b>4780</b></p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <sup>第1期</sup> 雷蛇 萨诺狼蛛专业版Cynosa Pro 游戏键盘 3色背光键盘
    </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
           <div class="col s6 cards-container" style="padding: 0 5px !important;">
       <div class="card">
         <div class="card-image">
            <img src="http://localhost/storage/uploads/5/Xiaomi100003077048@3x_c.png">
         </div>
         <div class="card-content">
            <div class="row">
             <div class="progress">
      <div class="determinate" id="par5" style="width: 0%"></div>
     </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
     <div class="col s8">
      <div class="contents event-status event-status-left">
       <p>目前人数 <b><span id="left5">0</span></b></p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col s4">
      <div class="contents event-status event-status-req">
       <p><b>3380</b></p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <sup>第1期</sup> 小米盒子4SE 高清网络机顶盒
    </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>               
</div></div>
```

How can I remove the gap of cards in `Materialize.css`?
The following CSS doesn't seem like working at all.

```
.cards-container {
  column-break-inside: avoid;
}

.card .card-image {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.card {
    width:100%;
    /*min-height:250px;*/
    background:rgba(255,255,255,1);
    border-radius:8px;
    text-align: center;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    /*margin: 10px 0px;*/
    padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    /*position: relative;*/
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please create a simplified demo with the code relevant to your question.

Comment: Which gap you're talking about?